# How to use encapsulation?

Tags: java, c#

After I read online E-book.They said the benefit of encapsulation is `"A class can change the data type of a field and users of the class do not need to change any of their code."`. I don't understand what they say in the point. What is the main meaning of the point? Can you give an example,please?

Comment: Here is a good article in java about ecapsulation. http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/encapsulation-in-java/ there are tons of tutorial online about encapsulation.

Comment: Googling the exact sentence you quoted, even with the quotes to have an exact match, already gives a bunch of results. And if you search for _encapsulation_ you'll get a gorillion more results about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple class Vehicles, which maintains a list:

```
public class Vehicles {

    private ArrayList<String> vehicleNames;

    Vehicles() {
        vehicleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void add(String vehicleName) {
        vehicleNames.add(vehicleName);
    }
}
```

This will be used by a client in the following way:

```
public class Client {

    Public static void main(String []args) {
        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
        vehicles.add("Toyota");
        vehicles.add("Mazda");
    }
}
```

Now if `Vehicles` changes its internal private `vehicleNames` field to be a `LinkedList` instead, Client would be unaffected. That is what the book is talking about, that the user/client does not need to make any changes to account for the changes in the class due to encapsulation.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is really important in Object-Oriented Programming. Using encapsulation, you can hide information from users who use your class library/API.

"And why do I need to hide stuff from the users?", you ask. There are a lot of reason. One main reason is that some users who are naughty or just don't know what the API is doing may mess with your classes and stuff. Let me give you an example.

Suppose you have a class here:

```
public class Computer {
    public int coreCount;
}
```

As you can see here, `coreCount` is declared `public`. That means all other classes can access it. Now imagine a naughty person do this:

```
Computer myPC = new Computer ();
myPC.coreCount = 0;
```

Even fools can tell that this doesn't make any sense. It might also affect your program's other stuff. Imagine you want to divide by the core count. An Exception would occur. So to prevent this, we should create setters and getters and mark the field `private`.

C# Version:

```
public class Computer {
    private int coreCount;
    public int CoreCount {
        get {return coreCount;}
        set {
            if (value > 0)
                coreCount = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Java version

```
public class Computer {
    private int coreCount;
    public int getCoreCount () {return coreCount;}
    public void setCoreCount (int value) {
        if (value > 0)
            coreCount = value;
}
```

Now no one can set the core count to non-positive values!

Comment: Now I really don't understand why I am downvoted. Is this not what OP is asking?

Comment: It's not just you. Look at the other answers on the post, including mine.

Comment: If this answers your question, accepting my answer will be very appreciated! @loemtheany

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example of encapsulation. Say we have a `Person` class, like so

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private String email;
  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public String getEmail() { return this.email; }

  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
}
```

And at some point, we decide we need to store these values not as a couple strings, but as a `HashMap` (for some reason or another).

We can change our internal representation without modifying the public interface of our `Person` class like so

```
class Person {
  HashMap<String, String> data;
  public Person() {
    this.data= new HashMap<String, String>();
  }
  public String getName() { return this.data.get("name"); }
  public String getEmail() { return this.data.get("email"); }

  public void setName(String name) { this.data.put("name", name); }
  public void setEmail(String email) { this.data.put("email", email); }
}
```

And from the client code perspective, we can still get and set Strings name and email without worrying about anything else.